# how to pass additional parameter to function `my_hook` of youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

```
import youtube_dl
def my_hook(d,`some parameter`):
    ...
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
   ydl.download("link" , 'some parameter')
```

How can i pass `some parameter` to `my_hook` function? I want to pass a socket object to `my_hook`  function to report the latest download progress to another machine. How can i pass it?

Comment: Hallo, what did you try so far ?

Comment: I just set up a websocket server and recv the youtube link and download it, and informing the client the progress of downloading. if we have one websocket (one client) we can use a global variable to pass the client websocket object so we can use it in `my_hook` to send the status of downloading. but if we have several downloading at the same time, i can't understand which `my_hook` to send the status of downloading to which client websocket obj . so i need to pass the client websocket obj to `my_hook` to send the status of downloading to the corresponding websocket obj, and i can't pass it

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import youtube_dl

def progress_hook( response ):
    ##  send  response['status']  to whatever subprocess you have going on.
    print( response['status'] )

ydl_opts = {
    'progress_hooks': [progress_hook],
    ##  other options, resolution & whatnot
}

link = 'm.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'

with youtube_dl .YoutubeDL( ydl_opts ) as ydl:
    ##  metadata = ydl .extract_info( link, download=False )
    ##  print( metadata )
    ydl .download( [link, ydl_opts] )
```

Comment: i khow how to get the current dowloading status, but the whole code is in a websocket server and i need to pass the websocket client object to `my_hook` to send the downloading status to the websocket client. just tell me how to pass something(variable) from `ydl.download` to `my_hook`

Comment: What, you mean like `argparse`?  There's SO articles on that already.

Comment: assume i get the youtube link by websocket and download them, i have several request at the same time downloading, i want to khow which `my_hook` belongs to which request (websocket of client) to inform them the status of downloading. i can't discriminate the requests

Comment: That would take a class with local instances of ydl.  Just tried running it with argparse, 'cuz I thought it'd be simple, but ydl starts complaining about unrecognized args.  Expected argparse would intercept them.  Yeah, that'll take some thought.  I need to sleep first though.

Comment: LOL. OK bro. comment it if you figured  out how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

```
import yt_dlp
def wrapper_hook(custom_param):
    def my_hook(d):
        print(custom_param)
        ...
    return my_hook

ydl_opts = {
    'progress_hooks':[wrapper_hook("custom")]
}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
   ydl.download("link")
```

This should work. NOTE: I have updated it for yt_dlp